# How to format data to incorporate a time dependent covariate in R

Tags: r

I am really struglling with manipulating my dataset to incorporate a time varying covariate for a cox regression and was wondering if some could show me how in R. SPSS does it but would really like to do the analysis in R.

Let me explain the sample data set below. There are 4 patients and all patients have an event.1 status as either 0 or 1. Event.1 has occured at time.1. Two patients have also an event.2 (patient number 2 and 4)

```
structure(list(id = 1:4, event.1 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), time.1 = c(11L, 
21L, 20L, 23L), event.2 = c(NA, 1L, NA, 1L), time.2 = c(NA, 11L, 
NA, 9L)), .Names = c("id", "event.1", "time.1", "event.2", "time.2"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Event.2 is a time dependent covariate and has happened at time.2 in patient 2 and patient 4. For me to be able to analyse the data and incorporate event.2 as a time dependent covariate i need to transform the data into long format which should appear as below:

```
structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), start = c(0L, 
0L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 11L), stop = c(11L, 11L, 21L, 20L, 11L, 22L), 
event.1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), event.2 = c(0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("id", "start", "stop", "event.1", 
"event.2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

As you can see both patient 2 and patient 4 now has two rows each assigned to them splitng the time course as per the occurence of event.2. Taking patient 2 as an example, the first row indicates 'start' time of 0 and 'stop' time of 11 with both 'event.1' and 'event.2' status as 0. The second row for patient 2 gives the information that at 'start' time of 11, 'event.2' occurred followed by 'event.1' occuring at 'stop' time of 21 months.

Simlarly in patient 4, the second row indicates that at 'start' time of 11, event.2 occured and follow up finished at 'stop' time of 22 at which time 'event.1' status was '0'.

Essentially, when a time dependent covariate ('event.2') occurs (event.2 == 1) then we get 2 rows for the same id. The first row starts from 'start' time of 0 and ends with a 'stop' time of the value which was originally time.2. For this row both event.1 and event.2 will be '0'. The second row will then be assigned a 'start' time of original 'time.2' and a 'stop' of the original 'time.1' with event.1 status as either '0' or '1' but event.2 staus as '1'.

Sorry for the verbose explanation but hopefullt that is clearer.
Any idea how i can manipulate my data frame to incorporate this time varying covariate in R?

Thanks in advance

Anoop

Comment: The question is somewhat unclear to me. Why are you using 10 month periods? Is that the true unit of time? If yes, what happens if you have a 30 month instance of patient 2? Is status 0 until the final 10 month observation?

Comment: Since this is a programming forum, not a statistics board like Crossvalidated, it's prly better to just describe exactly how to get from the 1st to the 2nd data frame (instead of relying on terms like time dependend covariate).